# Changing Int from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, integer

I want to change the playerCurScore integer (in ScoreManager script) from HarmEnemiesScript.

(Script attached to Object in Scene)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int playerScore;
    public int playerCurScore;

    public void Start()
    {
        playerScore = 0;
        playerCurScore = 0;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        playerCurScore = playerScore;
    }
}
```

(Script attached on Enemy)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HarmEnemies : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float enemyHealth;
    public float enemyCurHealth;
    public float playerDamage;

    public void Start()
    {
        enemyCurHealth = enemyHealth;
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider theCollision)
    {
        if(theCollision.tag == "Fireball")
        {
            enemyCurHealth = enemyCurHealth - playerDamage;
            Destroy (theCollision);
        }
        if(enemyCurHealth <= 0)
        {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I change the playerCurScore Int from HarmEnemies. I know that I have to use GetComponent and I can use playerCurScore++;

Comment: Burge: Can you please be more specific on the question? Can't see playerCurScore anywhere in the code.

Comment: @Anurag The HarmEnemy Script is attached to the Enemy. The Enemy will be destroyed after Health <= 0. So I think I have to add a script (Which will be the ScorePoints) to add the score in this script, before the enemy gets destroyed. BTW I have added the script now :) Im sorry for this.

Comment: There are several ways to get a reference to the ScoreManager class and then change the value. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551575/unity-how-to-access-a-variable-from-another-script-in-another-gameobject-throug)

Comment: The ScorePoint Script is attached to a EmptyGameObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it now, thank you for the static hint. my code looks like this now:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static float playerScore;
    public Text scoreCount;

    public void Update()
    {
        ScoreController ();
    }

    public void ScoreController()
    {
        scoreCount.text = "Score: " + playerScore;
        Debug.Log ("Score: " + playerScore);
    }
}




using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HarmEnemies : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float enemyHealth;
    public float enemyCurHealth;
    public float playerDamage;

    public void Start()
    {
        enemyCurHealth = enemyHealth;
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider theCollision)
    {
        if(theCollision.tag == "Fireball")
        {
            enemyCurHealth = enemyCurHealth - playerDamage;
            Destroy (theCollision);
        }

        if(enemyCurHealth <= 0)
        {
            ScoreManager.playerScore = (ScoreManager.playerScore + 1);
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making several mistakes. The main one is that the `ScoreManager` script should not be attached to the `EnemyGameObject`.

Make a separate GameObject and name it `ScoreManager`. Then find it in the scene and update the score.

```
 ScoreManager s = GameObject.Find("ScoreManager");
 s.SendMessage("incrementScore", amount);
```

---

In the ScoreManager class you need this:

```
 private static int score;

 public void incrementScore(int amount)
 {
     score += amount;
 }
```

---

If you are clever you make the whole ScoreManager class `static` and then it wouldn't even have to be a `MonoBehaviour`.

You would then call it like this:

```
 ScoreManager.incrementScore(amount);
```

Information about [static classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).