# CS0120 Cant set layer mask from different script

Tags: c#, game-physics, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where i want to change which objects my player can collide with by changing the layer mask, but every time I try to change the variable in a different script it throws this error

> Error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static
>   member `RaycastController.jumpableCollisionMask'

The code for where i create the variable:

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof (BoxCollider2D))]
public class RaycastController : MonoBehaviour {

    public LayerMask collisionMask;

    public LayerMask jumpableCollisionMask;
```

The code for where i set the variable

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerChanger : MonoBehaviour {

    public float numberOfPlayersPerLevel;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)){
            RaycastController.jumpableCollisionMask = 11;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using a setter but i couldn't get it to work. Thanks in advance and have a nice day =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jumpableCollisionMask = 11
```

not

```
RaycastController.jumpableCollisionMask = 11
```

---

Note that you likely have another problem:

You set layer masks (which are just `int`) like this:

```
int layerMaskDogs = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Dogs");
int layerMaskFruits = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Fruits");
```

ok?

Never use "= 11" or any number or other value.  In Unity it is now only possible to use the form `1<<LayerMask.NameToLayer("Blah")`

---

Finally note you are using `public` to declare the `LayerMask`.  That can be a bit confusing -- you only do that if you want to **set it in the editor**.  If that's what you want to do, fine. But if you don't need to do that, just use `private`.

---

Finally note that you have this is **TWO DIFFERENT SCRIPTS!!!**  This is the most basic problem in Unity. Fortunately it is easily solved:

-- add a **public variable** to your SECOND script

```
public class PlayerChanger : MonoBehaviour {
  public RaycastController myRC;
```

-- IN THE INSPECTOR take your "RaycastController" and **drag it to that public variable**

-- Now use it like this

```
public class PlayerChanger : MonoBehaviour {
     public RaycastController myRC;
     ...
     ...
     ...
     //whenever you need to use it...
     myRC.jumpableCollisionMask = 11;
```

Please read the literally 1000s of QA on this!  Example, [How to access a variable from another script in another gameobject through GetComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551575/how-to-access-a-variable-from-another-script-in-another-gameobject-through-getco)

Comment: hi @Paradizigmania hope it helps, don't hesitate to ask more questions

Comment: thanks for the answer. i just tried it but it returns with CS0103: The name `jumpableCollisionMask' does not exist in the current context

Comment: ah - you have them in TWO DIFFERENT SCRIPTS ?!?!?!