# Getting float variable of child object in uinty

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have Unit gameObject which contains 2 subOnjects in it: Monster and HealthBar.
Now Health has float - max_Health which I want to access using onTriggerEnter.

```
print(co.transform.GetChild(1));
```

Gives me "HealthBar" Which means I get correct subobject but now how can I get meaning of its float variable "max_Health"  ?

I've tryied this:

```
print(co.transform.GetChild(1).transform.Find("max_Health"));
```

But got Null. That's wrong. How can I get it ?

`print(co.transform.GetChild(1).Find("max_Health"));` **not working**

`print(co.transform.GetChild(1).Find("float max_Health"));` **not working.**

What else can be done ??????

**UPDATE**

```
GameObject GG = GameObject.Find("GameObject co.transform.GetChild(1)");
Health bScript = GG.GetComponent<Health>();
print(bScript.max_Health);
```

gives me error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Tower.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider co) (at Assets/Scripts/Tower.cs:23)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a variable from another script in another gameobject through GetComponent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551575/how-to-access-a-variable-from-another-script-in-another-gameobject-through-getco)

Comment: Tried that link. Didn't help

Comment: Your question does not show that you tried. I don't see GetComponent anywhere in your question. That is the correct way to do this, update your question to show what you tried with `GetComponent<YourClass>()`.

Comment: Probably I'm close but doing something wrong. As you can see I'm not pro with coding :) Can you check my last update ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Find()` at all in this case, if you can already access the GameObject's transform with `co.transform.GetChild(1)`. Just use `GetComponent()` with the results of `GetChild(1)`, like so: `co.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Health>()` This will give you a reference to the `Health` script component on the child, so you can access any (public) variables/methods you have there.

Comment: That worked thanks!!!

Comment: Great! If possible, could you click the Close link (it should be underneath the question) and mark the question to be closed on account of the aforementioned duplicate? Closing as duplicate can be very helpful for future readers, as it serves as a signpost towards solutions to common problems.

Comment: Sure, will do! Thanks again!

Comment: hi @david could you click either Close or Delete on this question  to close out the question and help keep the QA tidy, thanks

Comment: Joe, I did hit close as Serlite told me.