# Assign gameObject of a script via another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I assign a gameObject of one script through another script's gameObject? For example;
Script_1

```
public class Script_1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public OVRScript OVR;
}
```

Script_2

```
public class Script_2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Script_1 src_1;
    public GameObject Front;

  void Start()
    {
        src_1 = (Script_1) GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(Script_1));
        src_1.GetComponent<OVRScript >().OVR = Front //I am facing problem here
    }

}
```

Both GameObjects "OVR" and "Front" contain the `OVRScript`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a variable from another script in another gameobject through GetComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551575/how-to-access-a-variable-from-another-script-in-another-gameobject-through-getco)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know or see the `OVRScript` class but isn't `OVR` rather a member of `Script_1`?

And then you would want to use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) on the `Front` in order to get a component attached to it.

```
// If possible rather drag your Script_1 in here directly via the Inspector
[SeializeField] private Script_1 src_1;

void Start()
{
    // Now I would use find only as fallback
    if(!scr_1) src_1 = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Script_1>();

    // then you want to assign the OVR field of the 'src_1' of type 'Script_1'
    // and not use 'src_1.GetComponent<OVRScript>()' which would return
    // the reference of an 'OVRScript' component attached to the same GameObject as the Script_1
    //
    // And you want to fill it with the reference of an 'OVRScript' attached to 'Front'
    src_1.OVR = Front.GetComponent<OVRScript>();
}
```

(see [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html))

---

It would be even better if you directly define

```
public OVRScript Front;
```

now if you drag in a `GameObject` it a) is checked if this `GameObject` actually has a `OVRScript` attached, otherwise you can't drop it and b) instead of the `GameObject` reference already the `OVRScript` reference is serialized and stored so there is no need for `GetComponent` anymore:

```
[SeializeField] private Script_1 src_1;
public OVRScript Front;

void Start()
{
    // Now I would use find only as fallback
    if(!scr_1) src_1 = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Script_1>();

    src_1.OVR = Front;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
src_1.GetComponent<OVRScript>().OVR = Front.GetComponent<OVRScript>().OVR;
```